# HttpServletResponse is null in Around advice,what did i do wrong?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop

I need request and response of API call, I'm getting all request params that I need but the response is always null, I need HttpServletResponse response to get request body how can I do that?

```java
@Around("@annotation(Loggable)")
public Object loggable(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())).getRequest();
    ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest = new ServletWebRequest(request);
    HttpServletResponse response = servletWebRequest.getResponse();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how to ask good questions. Your own benefit will be good answers. In this AOP example, it is completely unclear which target class you want to intercept and what it returns. AOP sample code only makes sens if we see both the full aspect (not just a snippet of it) and one or more application classes. How can anyone know where to get your servlet response from if we don't see what you are intercepting? Plus, your sample code does not return anything, like this it will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Loggable is custom annotation defined and used in the controller method, `proceed` variable defined in above block of code should have response of the API.